# Need help appending URL segment to a specific URL in HTML using forms

Tags: html

My code here does appends "*?name=value*" to the url for Wikipedia.
What I need is for it to append a "*/userinput*" not all of that.

For example instead of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki?q=H I would want https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H with the user input being "H"

How would I go about this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Wiki Search</title> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki" method="get">
            <input name="q" type="text"/>
            <input type="submit" text="Search"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's not possible only in html, you better use some javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example using some JavaScript.

```js
const myForm = document.querySelector('#myForm')
myForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const src = myForm.getAttribute('action')
  const val = myForm.querySelector('input').value
  myForm.setAttribute('action', `${src}/${val}`)
  location.href = myForm.getAttribute('action')
})
```

```html
<form action="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki" method="get" id="myForm">
    <input name="q" type="text"/>
    <input type="submit" text="Search"/>
</form>
```